# log4j.properties Simple question

Tags: java, logging, log4j

log4j.logger.mylog    = debug, A1

I want to know 2 things,

1. what is "mylog" here?
2. what is "A" here?

Answer (score 2):

`mylog` is the *logger* name (which you pass to `Logger.getLogger()` in your code; you can also pass a class in which case the logger name is the name of the class). In fact in a configuration file it can be the *prefix* for a logger name - so in this case, any logger name *beginning* with `mylog` will use appender A1 (and possibly others).

`A1` is the *appender* name (which is configured elsewhere in the configuration file) - this determines where the actual output goes.

The ["short introduction to log4j"](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) is a good starting point for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

- `mylog` is the name of your logger (as requested in your code using [`Logger.getLogger("mylog")`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getLogger%28java.lang.String%29).
- A1 is the id of an appender that you defined in your configuration.